# torch.cuda.is_available() is False, when correct CUDA is installed. What could be wrong?

Tags: pytorch, gpu

I'm having some trouble getting pytorch to access the GPU. I know that there is an agreement of the CUDA version (11.8). I leave some additional information below, does anyone know what is going on?

In case it is relevant, I am working on an HPC. When connecting to the GPU via Jupyter Notebooks, there is no issue and I get `torch.cuda.is_available()=True`. It's only when submitting jobs with slurm scheduler that the problem arises.

This is what I get when I run the `collect_env` from pytorch:

```
PyTorch version: 2.1.0
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 11.8
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) (x86_64)
GCC version: (GCC) 10.3.0
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: Could not collect
Libc version: glibc-2.17

Python version: 3.9.18 (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:41:44)  [GCC 11.2.0] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Linux-3.10.0-1160.80.1.el7.x86_64-x86_64-with-glibc2.17
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: 11.8.89
CUDA_MODULE_LOADING set to: N/A
GPU models and configuration: Could not collect
Nvidia driver version: Could not collect
cuDNN version: Could not collect
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A
Is XNNPACK available: True

CPU:
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                128
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-127
Thread(s) per core:    1
Core(s) per socket:    64
Socket(s):             2
NUMA node(s):          8
Vendor ID:             AuthenticAMD
CPU family:            23
Model:                 49
Model name:            AMD EPYC 7742 64-Core Processor
Stepping:              0
CPU MHz:               2250.000
CPU max MHz:           2250.0000
CPU min MHz:           1500.0000
BogoMIPS:              4499.65
Virtualization:        AMD-V
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              512K
L3 cache:              16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-15
NUMA node1 CPU(s):     16-31
NUMA node2 CPU(s):     32-47
NUMA node3 CPU(s):     48-63
NUMA node4 CPU(s):     64-79
NUMA node5 CPU(s):     80-95
NUMA node6 CPU(s):     96-111
NUMA node7 CPU(s):     112-127
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc extd_apicid aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 fma cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt tce topoext perfctr_core perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_l2 cpb cat_l3 cdp_l3 hw_pstate sme ssbd rsb_ctxsw ibrs ibpb stibp vmmcall fsgsbase bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 cqm rdt_a rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb sha_ni xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local retpoline_amd clzero irperf xsaveerptr arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale vmcb_clean flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold avic v_vmsave_vmload vgif umip overflow_recov succor smca

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.26.0
[pip3] torch==2.1.0
[pip3] torchaudio==2.1.0
[pip3] torchvision==0.16.0
[pip3] triton==2.1.0
[conda] blas                      1.0                         mkl  
[conda] libjpeg-turbo             2.0.0                h9bf148f_0    pytorch
[conda] mkl                       2023.1.0         h213fc3f_46343  
[conda] mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h5eee18b_1  
[conda] mkl_fft                   1.3.8            py39h5eee18b_0  
[conda] mkl_random                1.2.4            py39hdb19cb5_0  
[conda] numpy                     1.26.0           py39h5f9d8c6_0  
[conda] numpy-base                1.26.0           py39hb5e798b_0  
[conda] pytorch                   2.1.0           py3.9_cuda11.8_cudnn8.7.0_0    pytorch
[conda] pytorch-cuda              11.8                 h7e8668a_5    pytorch
[conda] pytorch-mutex             1.0                        cuda    pytorch
[conda] torchaudio                2.1.0                py39_cu118    pytorch
[conda] torchtriton               2.1.0                      py39    pytorch
[conda] torchvision               0.16.0               py39_cu118    pytorch
```

And with `nvidia-smi`:

```
Sun Oct  8 17:52:01 2023       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 520.61.05    Driver Version: 520.61.05    CUDA Version: 11.8     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:06:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 23%   23C    P8     7W / 250W |      1MiB / 11264MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Finally the bash script:

#!/bin/bash

```
#SBATCH --partition=gpu
#SBATCH --qos=job_gpu
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:gtx1080ti:1

home='/storage/usr/'

module load Anaconda3
module load CUDA/11.8.0

source activate myenv
sbatch --output=${home}/output/%j_%x.out --error=${home}/error/%j_%x.err \
 ${home}'test_script.py'
```

and the simple test python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9

import torch 

if __name__ == '__main__':

    device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
    print(device)
```

I tried to follow the installation for this version with

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

and also installed conda-tools:

```
conda install -c "nvidia/label/cuda-11.8.0" cuda-toolkit
```